# Child process hanging after call to system()

Tags: c, fork

The problem is that either the parent or child process is not exiting. The child process prints its message and then the program hangs. Could be stuck at system() because this doesn't happen when the system() call is removed. The unhide_string() filters out non-letters and args is defined elsewhere. The command "cmd" that's passed to get_page() is valid.

```c
int get_page(char* cmd) {
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char* args_s = unhide_string(args);
    if (args_s == NULL) {
        printf("Please run me again :)\n");
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        get_page(args_s);
        printf("Guess what I did :)\n");
    }
    
    free(args_s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system` doesn't return until that process is done. If you open something that doesn't terminate you get stuck. If you need more control, consider doing your own `fork`/`exec` instead.

Comment: Okay, but this is the command: `curl --silent --output /dev/null wikipedia.org`. Running that in a terminal terminates just fine. Shouldn't system be returning then?

Comment: Are you sure that it hangs ? You have two processes: the father finishes immediately and give back the hand to the calling shell which displays the prompt.  Meanwhile the child calls system() to run the command and then it displays "Guess what I did :)". The display is done after the prompt display of the shell. But if you type return, you get back another prompt no ?

Comment: It "exits" because the working directory is printed again, then next to that, the "Guess what I did" message prints, and then a blinking cursor under that. The message is only printed once.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by having the parent wait for the child process to finish. This allowed the program to properly terminate.

Revised fork code:

```c
if (fork() == 0) {
    get_page(args_s);
    printf("Guess what I did :)\n");
} else {
    waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
}
```